# How can I get a Url that include Path of a Json File instead of Passing the Locally Path Using Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

Is there any way to upload the Credential File to the Firebase and only pass a path for this file from firebase to authenticate.

For Example:

here I need to pass the credential file which is in my local computer I need to pass a path from the internet maybe by uploading the credential file "serviceAccountKey.json" to the firebase and get a Url which include the path of this file on the internet.

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved This issue Instead of Generating a URL Which include the Path of the Json Credentials File and it won't be secure I solved it by Creating a New Json File then passing the name of the New Json File to the Credentials File Path It Works:

```
firebase_credentials = {
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "",
      "client_id": "",
      "auth_uri": "",
      "token_uri": "",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
      "client_x509_cert_url": ""
    }
    with open("firebase_credentials.json", "w") as write_file:
        json.dump(firebase_credentials, write_file)
    cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate('firebase_credentials.json')
```

And That's It GOOD LUCK...

Answer (score 0):

The `serviceAccountKey.json` file contains the credentials that grant anyone who has them administrative access to your project.

If the `serviceAccountKey.json` file would be stored in a publicly accessible place, everyone could get at that file and use it to gain administrative access to your project. They could write whatever code they want to manipulate your projects, and you user's data in there.

For this reason, the file should only be accessible to people who are trusted with such access, typically the collaborators on your Firebase project. That's why these credentials are usually stored on the local machine of each developer, and on production machines only.

Comment: You are Right but if I put the credential file in a very long strange url for example:
www.paths/3424234/343242gdsf.com
it is to hard to guest the url path no body can access only who knows this URL that's my idea 

The reson is that I need to deploy this app to heroku and heroku can't read the local path is there any way to Solve it?